# Is there a way to trigger the event in html

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me here. I am trying to trigger the button post which the function should get called and contents should be displayed

Not working (When button is incorporate)

```
<button id="alert" type="button">Calling car properties</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("alert").onclick = function car(seats,engine,theradio) {
this.seats=seats;
this.engine=engine;
this.theradio=theradio;
var work_car= new car("cloth","V-7","Tape Deck");
var fun_car= new car("leather","V-8","C Player");
var engine_type= work_car.engine;
var seat_type= fun_car.seats;
var radio_type= fun_car.theradio;
document.write("I want a car with "+seat_type+" seats.<br />");
document.write("It also needs a "+engine_type+" engine.<br />");
document.write(radio_type);

var number = Math.random();
document.write("It also needs a "+number+" engine.<br />");
}
</script>
```

working without button

```
<script>
function car(seats,engine,theradio) {
this.seats=seats;
this.engine=engine;
this.theradio=theradio;
}
var work_car= new car("cloth","V-7","Tape Deck");
var fun_car= new car("leather","V-8","C Player");
var engine_type= work_car.engine;
var seat_type= fun_car.seats;
var radio_type= fun_car.theradio;
document.write("I want a car with "+seat_type+" seats.<br />");
document.write("It also needs a "+engine_type+" engine.<br />");
document.write(radio_type);

var number = Math.random();
document.write("It also needs a "+number+" engine.<br />");
</script>
```

Comment: judging by the code you have a stack overflow

Comment: Define "not working". Note that [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) may not be the best approach--it *may* be what you intend, but it rarely is.

Comment: You bind the named constructor function of your "car" to onclick. It should be left alone and onclick should rather be another&anonymous function that uses it.

Comment: @Tobias. Sorry didn get you

Comment: You have a named function `car`. Inside of the function you call the function `car`. Inside of the function you call the function `car`. Inside ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you call `car` function recursively. To resolve the problem just rename the `onclick` event name and keep `car` function.

```js
        function car(seats, engine, theradio) {
            this.seats = seats;
            this.engine = engine;
            this.theradio = theradio;
        }

        document.getElementById("alert").onclick = function event() {
            
            var work_car = new car("cloth", "V-7", "Tape Deck");
            var fun_car = new car("leather", "V-8", "C Player");
            var engine_type = work_car.engine;
            var seat_type = fun_car.seats;
            var radio_type = fun_car.theradio;
            document.write("I want a car with " + seat_type + " seats.<br />");
            document.write("It also needs a " + engine_type + " engine.<br />");
            document.write(radio_type);

            var number = Math.random();
            document.write("It also needs a " + number + " engine.<br />");
        }
```

```html
  <button id="alert" type="button">Calling car properties</button>
```

Another important thing you must notice is `document.write`. probably better way is create tag and append it the body. Like this:

```
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.innerHTML = "I want a car with " + seat_type + " seats.<br />";

document.body.append(div1);
```

Comment: hi Ali, I tried as you said as well. But not working. Just posted the code here. Please refer

Comment: Please put `button` tag  before the `script` tag

Comment: I tried that as well. bit Not working. Please see my code :)

Comment: You can click on the `Run code snippet` and see that everything is OK.

Comment: it is working here. But the same code i copied but not working :( Let me check

Comment: Yes. But just for curiosity, why my approach did not work? Calling function directly?

Comment: Because of recursive calling. you call the `car` method in `car` method recursively

Answer (score 0):

Edited

```
<script>
function car(seats, engine, theradio) {
            this.seats = seats;
            this.engine = engine;
            this.theradio = theradio;
        }

        document.getElementById("alert").onclick = function event() {
            debugger
            var work_car = new car("cloth", "V-7", "Tape Deck");
            var fun_car = new car("leather", "V-8", "C Player");
            var engine_type = work_car.engine;
            var seat_type = fun_car.seats;
            var radio_type = fun_car.theradio;
            document.write("I want a car with " + seat_type + " seats.<br />");
            document.write("It also needs a " + engine_type + " engine.<br />");
            document.write(radio_type);

            var number = Math.random();
            document.write("It also needs a " + number + " engine.<br />");
        }
        </script>
<button id="alert" type="button">Calling car properties</button>
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation for what your code aims to do. This is useful for people arriving at the question, to help them understand what this does.

Answer (score 0):

Added button before script

```
<script>
function car(seats, engine, theradio) {
            this.seats = seats;
            this.engine = engine;
            this.theradio = theradio;
        }

        document.getElementById("alert").onclick = function event() {
            debugger
            var work_car = new car("cloth", "V-7", "Tape Deck");
            var fun_car = new car("leather", "V-8", "C Player");
            var engine_type = work_car.engine;
            var seat_type = fun_car.seats;
            var radio_type = fun_car.theradio;
            document.write("I want a car with " + seat_type + " seats.<br />");
            document.write("It also needs a " + engine_type + " engine.<br />");
            document.write(radio_type);

            var number = Math.random();
            document.write("It also needs a " + number + " engine.<br />");
        }
        
<button id="alert" type="button">Calling car properties</button>
</script>
```

Comment: This is not correct.  you put your button in script tag! Please put `button` tag in the body tag and then put script tag

Comment: Please don’t post multiple answers.